# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python

I set up a Python venv in a directory and then installed matplotlib in that environment. In the root directory I created a .py file and tried to run:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

I got an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'.
matplotlib is in ~/Desktop/Matplotlib/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib
```

In the error message there appear a couple of paths but not the one I need, apparently.

How can I fix this? I am using VS code.

I am stumped I don't know what more to do. I thought it would be recognized automatically but it isn't.

Comment: Sounds like your VS Code is set up to use another interpreter rather than `venv/bin/python3.10`, you can check it in the settings. Also, please format the code and errors in the question to make it more readable

Comment: Does it work from the commandline?